# Why does Selenium IDE sometimes fail to click the submit button?

Tags: selenium-ide

I have a Selenium IDE (version 1.7.2) test that I use to test the registration flow on my site.

In this test, I simulate signing up for several different accounts.  To do this, I recorded myself signing up for several accounts.

When I play the tests back, some of the accounts are registered ok, but other times the Submit button is clicked (the action turns yellow in the IDE) but it hangs, refusing to fail (turn red) or go on.  However, if I manually click the submit button in the browser window again during the test, the test will continue and it will mark the submit button green as if it passed correctly.

How can I get it to click the submit button correctly the first time?  Or is there a way to automatically get it to re-click if it times out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using clickAndWait??if yes then change it to click and put pause after click command.Or try to locate element by different ways, or hit enter to submit form as

```
`keyDown  | locator of element/last field | \13`
```

as twall suggested

Comment: Changing to "Click" from "ClickAndWait" and putting a pause both before and after solved the problem for me.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Did you use the command `waitForElementPresent` before calling the `click` command ?

Answer (score 0):

I have found out that is more secure to just `sendKeys("\n")` (simulationg an 'enter' key press) instead of using `click()` when filling out forms. Don't ask me why, but it was a big relieve to me, after I had found out.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I was talking about the Java implementation.